# Angularjs filter in controller include two params

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm using Angularjs ,I have one problem,please help me.

When I  code   `$filter('orderBy')(source,"-nowsuccess");`
   the source can `orderBy` nowsuccess 
   But I code `$filter('orderBy')(source,"-nowsuccess","-total_order");`
   the source can't `orderBy`  nowsuccess and  total_order
   this is a bug? 
   Please tell me  correct way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy):

> $filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse)

I think that what you want is to order by `-nowsuccess` first and then by `-total_order`, if that's the case you could do it like this:

```
$filter('orderBy')(source,['-nowsuccess','-total_order']);
```

Comment: I try it  but can't resolve;    It just like $filter('orderBy')(dealData($scope.list, limit),"-nowsuccess")  and $filter('orderBy')(dealData($scope.list, limit),"-total_order") .The end  sorted by total_order.

Comment: It just like $filter('orderBy')(dealData($scope.list, limit),"-nowsuccess")

Comment: @user3898669 I just updated the answer, my apologies for misleading you! Please let me know if it works, thanks!